# Can I Get Access Token on Azure without registering my autotesting app?

Tags: c#, .net, api, azure-active-directory, autotest

I write API autotests (using C#, HttpClient) for application deployed on azure. There were added authorizations - Authentication with Azure Active Directory and JWT Authorization using the Bearer scheme. Of course all my tests now fail with 401 error. To fix them I need to get Bearer token and add it to request header. 
There a lot of tutorials how to do it, but main idea is I need registrate my autotest app on Azure and use secrets from it to send POST request to login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token.

On my previous project that used apigee it was wery simpe - POST JSON with creds and apikey and get token in response.

Is it possible to get token without registration fake app on Azure, just sending some requests with my test user credentials? Like one can do on apigee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy I solved this problem without registering apps on Azure. I  went another way and imitated login throw MS form using HttpWebRequest class. So there is no UI part, just three http requests and that suits me perfect for my API autotests. Big advantage, I can tests application behavior for users with different access level not having to register many fake applications on Azure to imitate different users.

Comment: Hello, Can you please give me the high level steps how we can implement the embedded report without app register in Azure. your answer is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Where would you get the credentials if not the registered app?
You need a signed token from Azure AD.
It will only give you one if you prove your app's identity and AAD confirms it.
You have to register the testing app.

Comment: Where would you get the credentials if not the registered app? I want to use user creds as can do with any notMicrosoft vendors. It's described in question as example - Apigee, which has authentification server too.

Comment: User authentication is also always done as an app acting on behalf of the user. So you need an app.